# How do I troubleshoot a "Internal .NET runtime error" (related to VS 2010 crash)

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework

My Visual Studio has started crashing every time I open certain solutions.  It tells me "sorry but VS 2010 has encountered an error etc" and then logs this event in the event log:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 7914A32E (79140000) with exit code 80131506.
```

VS is working perfectly otherwise.  All of my unaffected solutions open, compile, and run no problem.  The computer is Win 2k3 server, .NET 4.0 installed.

Comment: Does the same happen if a *faulty* solution is opened on another computer? The information is barely enough to make anything out of. If you could dig up anything else or compare results when varying parameters, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: I'm getting a similar thing whenever I run a search and change the scope, but only from the floating search box, and not the Find > Replace menu. However, I can at least narrow down the problem, which you need to do. Find out whether you can replicate it in different circumstances, identify what's NOT causing it to rule it out, etc.